# Can't run npm, packages code contains Null Safety

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

When I tried to run my web project with `npm run serve`, I get this error

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
> 5:53:56 PM
>
> error  in
> ./node_modules/primevue/virtualscroller/virtualscroller.esm.js
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (191:25) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> ```
> |         scrollTo(options) {
> |             this.lastScrollPos = this.both ? { top: 0, left: 0 } : 0;
>              this.element?.scrollTo(options); 
> |         }, 
> |         scrollToIndex(index, behavior = 'auto') {
> ```
>
> @ ./node_modules/primevue/multiselect/multiselect.esm.js 6:0-55
> 1039:25-40  @ ./src/main.js  @ multi
> (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node
> (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

This weren't used to be a problem. I have been doing this project for the past 2-3 months now and this comes up suddenly out of nowhere. There were actually two errors, all of them have Null Safety `?` in it. I manually edited one of the null safety out, and sure enough, the error stops appearing. But that's a temp solution at best.

It says I need a loader, but I don't understand it. I don't have webpack install and setup. Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: " I don't have webpack install and setup" - the question has this tag. If you use vue-cli then you need to mention this. "npm run serve" is not something that goes without saying

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I don't have a clue in any of this which is the reason for including that tag there. Nevertheless, thank you to whoever posted the links. I have been trying to solve it for 2 days now.